# How do I go about solving this problem?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A card from a pack of 52 cards is lost. From the remaining cards of the pack, two cards are drawn and are found to be both diamonds. Find the probability of the lost card being a diamond?
could you explain what is the relation between the lost card and the cards we draw. I mean how could you go about solving this ridiculous question but there exists a definite solution. If I am wrong please tell me what am I missing.

Comment: please up vote if you think this is a nice problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the lost card is a diamond, you are drawing from a pack with $12$ diamonds and $39$ other cards.  What is the chance you get two diamonds from that pack?  If the lost card is not a diamond, you are drawing from a pack with $13$ diamonds and $38$ other cards.  What is the chance you draw two diamonds from that pack?  It is higher, which shows how the suit of the lost card matters.

Really what you are asked is to compare the chance of drawing three diamonds with the chance of drawing one non-diamond and two diamonds from a standard pack.

Answer (score 1):

The lost card influence the probability of drawing certain patterns of cards from the remaining deck.

Let $L$ be the event that the lost card is a diamond.
Let $D$ be the event that two cards drawn from the remaining deck are diamonds.
We are interested in $Pr(L|D)$

From Bayes rule, we have $$Pr(L|D)=\frac{Pr(D|L)Pr(L)}{Pr(D)}$$

Also note that $$Pr(D)=Pr(D|L)Pr(L)+Pr(D|L^c)Pr(L^c)$$

These are the ingredients needed, are you able to compute it?